# Is my proof (that the summit angles of a Saccheri quadrilateral are congruent) valid?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, triangles, quadrilateral

In Greenberg's (2008) textbook, the following proof that the summit angles of a Saccheri quadrilateral are congruent is given on p. 178.

> By hypothesis and SAS, $\triangle DBA \cong \triangle CAB$.  Then by SSS, $\triangle DCB \cong \triangle CDA$.  Hence $\angle C \cong \angle D$ by angle addition.

The proof is accompanied by the following diagram:

[image: Figure accompanying Greenberg's proof]

I do see that Greenberg's proof is valid-- although I am surprised that he did not include an argument right before his last sentence showing that the ray $\overrightarrow{CB}$ is between $\overrightarrow{CA}$ and $\overrightarrow{CD}$ and that the ray $\overrightarrow{DA}$ is between $\overrightarrow{DC}$ and $\overrightarrow{DB}$.  This argument might take a couple sentences and make the proof longer.

To my mind, a more direct proof would be:

*By hypothesis and SAS, $\triangle DBA \cong \triangle CAB$.  Then by SSS, $\triangle DCB \cong \triangle CDA$.  Hence $\angle C \cong \angle D$ as **corresponding angles in the congruent triangles $\triangle DCB$ and $\triangle CDA$.***

Is my altered proof valid?  If not, what is the error in my reasoning?

(I am just puzzled as to why Greenberg would not take this more direct route-- assuming it is correct.)

**Reference**

Greenberg, M. J. (2008). *Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries:  Development and History  (4th ed.). New York, NY:  W. H. Freedman and Company*

Comment: spelled Greenberg. I'm in chapter 10.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the correction!  I guess I was pretty tired when I posted this question.